# Share file via intent android to whatsapp with fingerprint on not work

Tags: android, share, whatsapp, fingerprint

Hi I'm sharing file using intent.
And work well, share to whatsapp too.

```
fun shareFile(fileList: List<File>) {
        activity?.let {
            val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
            val uriList = fileList.map { file ->
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        it.baseContext, it.applicationContext?.packageName + ".provider", file)
            }

            target.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ArrayList(uriList))
            target.type = "application/pdf"
            target.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
            target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(target, ""))
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem if whatsapp with fingerprint on.
Share file not work.

Any suggestion to share on this case?

Thank you

Comment: Pls put ur code here. we don't know what u have done

Comment: Check my solution it may help to you my second snippet code to sharing image to social media

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the solution 
I should not include this code

```
target.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
```

so remove this code, share will work on whatsapp with fingerprint on

Thanks for all the reply